# The simulated application quit

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, exit

I'm using MAC OS X mountain lion (10.8.4) and xcode 4.6. My IOS simulator gives error that "The simulated application quit, switch sdk"..........

Firstly I tried to reset ios simulator, but its not working.
Secondly, I tried to delete folder "6.1" under ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
But i'm unable to find iPhone Simulator folder under Application support.
Thirdly, I uninstalled the xcode 4.6 by draging it to trash. And then installed it again, but the same error appears whenever i try to run any application.

I think, i'm not uninstalling the xcode properly. To uninsatll completely when I type following command
`/Applications/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` In resoponse I get "Command not found" tried with different commands. Nothing worked. I have wasted my last 12hours to get this work but couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Mountain Lion the Library folder that is situated in the user's account folder is hidden by default. I just unhide it then deleted the iPhone Simulator folder situated in the Library/Application Support and then restarted the xCode everything is OK. 
So, stupid problem if you know just 10sec are enough to solve this. Thank God I found myself. 
May be someone can find help from this.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  It solved my problem trying to get a Xamarin iOS project to run through the iPhone Simulator.